# Remoção de células no ínicio de uma lista

Tags: c

Tô com esse probleminha de remover um elemento do inicio de uma lista, mesmo fazendo o esquema no desenho eu não consegui. O mais estranho é que ele funciona com até 3 elementos, a partir do 4 o cmd (que to usando gcc pra compilar) para de responder. Alguma ideia?

```
    typedef struct evento_t {
    double tempo;
    char descricao[50];
    int id_origem, id_destino;
    struct evento_t *prox;
    } evento_t;

    void eventos_remover_inicio (evento_t **lista) {

    evento_t *auxiliar = *lista;

    if (*lista == NULL)
        printf ("Lista vazia\n");

    else 
        *lista = auxiliar->prox;

    free(auxiliar);

}
```

Comment: A única coisa "errada" que estou vendo é que depois de verificar se a lista está vazia, você ainda deixa que seja realizado `free` na lista vazia: `free(auxiliar) => free(NULL)` se `*lista == NULL`. Mesmo assim, se o ambiente seguir o padrão, isto [não deve gerar efeitos colaterais](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) ("_If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed_"). Você precisa mostrar o código que declara e inicializa uma lista e remove os elementos.

Answer (score 2):

O único potencial problema que enxergo nesse código é caso você esteja chamando com algo semelhante a isso:

```
evento_t **lista;
lista = NULL;
eventos_remover_inicio(lista);
```

Nesse caso a função irá dar problema pois não existe um teste de integridade do ponteiro `*lista` antes do seu uso.
Se for esse seu problema eu recomendaria algo assim:

```
void eventos_remover_inicio (evento_t **lista) {

    if(lista == NULL) 
    {
        return;
    }

    evento_t *auxiliar = *lista;

    if (*lista == NULL)
         printf ("Lista vazia\n");

    else 
         *lista = auxiliar->prox;

    free(auxiliar);
}
```

Porém ficaria bem mais fácil de entender o problema se você postasse o código que utiliza essa função e está dando problema.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi a necessidade de utilizar ponteiro para ponteiro em 'lista'. O que caracteriza uma lista é o fato de seus elementos terem ponteiros para elementos do mesmo tipo; struct evento_t *lista; lista = malloc( sizeof( evento_t ), 1 );//ou algo parecido, esqueci como se usa malloc.
lista->prox = malloc( sizeof( evento_t ), 1 );

Comment: Alem disso, voce verifica a validade do primeiro ponteiro em if( lista == NULL ); seja, lista pode apontar para um ponteiro, e este ainda pode ser nulo.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Tente se basear neste exemplo.

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

// Como declarar o root da lista ligada
Node *root = NULL;

void removeFirstNode(Node *list){
    Node *aux = list;
    if(list == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        list = aux->next;
        free(aux);
    }
}
```